# How to get the max of a count

Tags: sql-server

I work on the stack-exchange database for an university project. I would like to get the most popular tags per year.

I have make this request :

```
SELECT tagName
     , year(creationDate) AS annee
     , count(tagName) AS nbApparitions
FROM tags
JOIN postTags 
ON (tags.Id = postTags.tagId)
JOIN posts
ON (postTags.postId = posts.Id)
GROUP BY tagName, year(creationDate)
```

The result of this request is the count for each tags and each years. I would like this :

```
2016 JavaScript 123456
2015 PHP 123456
2014 HTML 123456
...
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT tagName , annee , MAX(nbApparitions)
FROM  
  (
    SELECT tagName
         , year(creationDate) AS annee
         , count(tagName) AS nbApparitions
   FROM tags
   JOIN postTags ON (tags.Id = postTags.tagId)
   JOIN posts    ON (postTags.postId = posts.Id)
   GROUP BY tagName, year(creationDate)
)A
GROUP BY tagName , annee
```

Comment: I've already use a request like this but it doesn't work (same problem)

Comment: @Mattasse what do you mean by it doesn't work? what is wrong with the output ?

Comment: this query return me the same result like my wrong query

Comment: Have you another solutions?